# RealVNC Server on UBUNTU 20.10 (ARM64) on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

RealVNC only provides a 32bit app for Raspberry Pi OS (32bit) and not a 64bit native application, at least for now. I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 on my Raspberry and need to use RealVNC to remotely access the system, as I don't know how to use SSH and I'm not interested in learning. how i can using vnc RealVNC Server on UBUNTU 20.10 (ARM64) on Raspberry Pi 4?

Comment: Note that this is breaking the licence conditions that RealVNC® Limited provides their proprietary binary to the Raspberry Pi OS distribution. `/usr/share/doc/realvnc-vnc-server/copyright` states that the binary is only for use on *… the Raspberry Pi Foundation’s official supported operating system*.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got it working after losing hours searching the Internet for several consecutive problems I got.

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
$ sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install libx11-6
```

Download the next 10 files from https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware ... opt/vc/lib

```
libbcm_host.so
libvcos.so
libmmal.so
libmmal_core.so
libmmal_components.so
libmmal_util.so
libmmal_vc_client.so
libchiq_arm.so
libvcsm.so
libcontainers.so
```

These 10 files above need to be copied to /usr/lib.

```
$ sudo apt install gdebi
$ sudo gdebi VNC-Server-6.7.2-Linux-ARM.deb
$ sudo systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced.service
$ sudo systemctl enable vncserver-virtuald.service
$ sudo systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced.service
$ sudo systemctl start vncserver-virtuald.service
$ sudo vnclicensewiz
$ sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment “WaylandEnable=false”

Reboot the system and all is working. I hope this was helpful to someone.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! One thing I don't understand is why did you add `armhf` architecture if you didn't install any packages for it. But then, I don't use Ubuntu or VNC, so I probably missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a native arm64 build available in the raspberrypi.org repos, direct link to the deb package here:
http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/realvnc-vnc/realvnc-vnc-server_6.7.2.43081_arm64.deb

Comment: `Unable to install realvnc-vnc-server: The following packages have unmet dependencies:`.
And no dependencies listed :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is my script that puts things together: Gist link: [Install RealVNC server on arm64 Linux](https://gist.github.com/skazemi/67a28afb77e366d82a4eb9353373c5f2)

```bsh
mkdir realvncserversetup && cd realvncserversetup
echo Add armhf arch
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf && sudo apt update

echo Download and install RealVNC server
wget -nv https://www.realvnc.com/download/file/vnc.files/VNC-Server-6.7.4-Linux-ARM.deb && sudo apt install ./VNC-Server-6.7.4-Linux-ARM.deb

echo Download and install dependencies
files=( libbcm_host.so libvcos.so libmmal.so libmmal_core.so libmmal_components.so \
    libmmal_util.so libmmal_vc_client.so libvchiq_arm.so libvcsm.so libcontainers.so )
for i in "${files[@]}"
do
    wget -nv https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/raw/master/opt/vc/lib/$i
done
sudo mv *.so /usr/lib/
cd ..

echo Enable VNC service on boot
sudo systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced.service
echo Start VNC service
sudo systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried saeedkazemi script and could not log in with VNC. Ran parts of Sajjad Aemmi's answer:

```
sudo systemctl enable vncserver-virtuald.service
sudo systemctl start vncserver-virtuald.service
sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

and remove '#' to Uncomment `WaylandEnable=false`
reboot
and then was able to log in with no problem.
Not sure what the reason to run `sudo vnclicensewiz` was for.

Comment: Please edit it so it is readable !

Answer (score 0):

I just got vncserver functional on my Pi 4b with Ubuntu 21.10.
I had it previously working with vncserver version 6.7.2 on ubuntu 20.10, but when I upgraded ubuntu to 21.10 and at the same time upgraded vncserver to 6.7.4 it had a library mismatch.

Copying in all the library files in the gist script shown by saeedkazemi above then restarting the 2 services listed there made it work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).